# amcharts drill-down map countries clickable

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

The drill-down map example has the `index.html` file which references three relevant javascript files.

1. index.js
2. continentsLow.js
3. worldLow.js

Now various references point to the definition of an [array of areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307377/amcharts-interactive-map-making-selected-states-a-clickable-link#49361414) that allow [url and target to be specified](https://amcharts.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203002122-How-do-I-hyperlink-country-or-other-area-to-some-URL-).

But it is not readily obvious which javascript file would carry this load.

The relevant section of the index.js file to my eyes is:

```
// Countries
var countriesSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
var countries = countriesSeries.mapPolygons;
countriesSeries.visible = false; // start off as hidden
countriesSeries.exclude = ["AQ"];
countriesSeries.geodata = am4geodata_worldLow;
countriesSeries.useGeodata = true;
// Hide each country so we can fade them in
countriesSeries.events.once("inited", function() {
  hideCountries();
});
```

The `worldLow`file seems a more appropriate spot  as it defines the countries polygons

```
am4internal_webpackJsonp(["fcaa"],{ATzU:function(e,t,o){"use strict";Object.defineProperty(t,"__esModule",{value:!0});window.am4geodata_worldLow={type:"FeatureCollection",
features:[{type:"Feature",geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[179.2223,-8.554],[179.2023,-8.4653],[179.2312,-8.5048],[179.2223,-8.554]]]},properties:{name:"Tuvalu",id:"TV"},id:"TV"},
{type:"Feature",geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[3.4624,-54.4471],[3.3461,-54.4511],[3.3669,-54.3997],[3.4814,-54.4001],[3.4624,-54.4471]]]},properties:{name:"Bouvet Island",id:"BV"},id:"BV"},
{type:"Feature",geometry:{type:"Polygon",coordinates:[[[-5.3345,36.1623],[-5.3382,36.1122],[-5.3562,36.1264],[-5.3551,36.1455],[-5.3345,36.1623]]]},[...]
```

while I attempted to add a `url` attribute in this array, it failed.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links you referenced are all for v3 of amCharts, whereas your code is for v4.

Here's the v4 Drill-down Map demo online: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/drill-down-map/ (I'll be using this as a base for the code below).

It's not clear what your question is, I'm going to presume you're trying to make countries clickable to a link. The [`url` property of a `MapPolygon`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mappolygon/#url_property) is the right place to make these changes.

You can either assign it directly or via [binding property fields to data](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/#Binding_properties_to_data).

To assign it directly, you can wait til the series has loaded, e.g. via its `"inited"` [event](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/event-listeners/), then use the series' `getPolygonById()` method to grab the country by its ISO2 ID. So, e.g. if you wanted Canada to click through to google:

```js
countriesSeries.events.on("inited", function() {
  var canada  = countriesSeries.getPolygonById('CA');
  canada.url = "https://www.google.com/search/?q=canada";
});
```

To bind the `url` property of `MapPolygon`s to a field that may appear in data you provide to the series, set the series' [template](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/list-templates/)'s `propertyFields.url` to the name of the matching field in the data object (let's say we'll use `"url"` in that case, too), e.g.:

```js
countrySeries.mapPolygons.template.propertyFields.url = "url";
```

Now just [pass data to the series](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/#In_line_data), e.g. if you want the United States to click through to google.com, pass an array with a single object whose `id` is `"US"` and `"url"` is `"http://google.com"`:

```js
countriesSeries.data = [
  {
    id: "US",
    url: "https://www.google.com"
  }
];
```

Here's a demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/6b8bffc714a966304a8f29d6939ee064

Comment: excellent response with reference to docs ( I had missed the inline bit...) and illustrating two ways of getting there.  One item of note, while the code provided above acts as designed, the code pen has the ISO 2-character country code value for ID revealed in the hover over the country.

Comment: Thanks! v4 is a whole new remake with new, possibly unfamiliar paradigms of doing things, so I try and link to documentation here and there. As for the iso2 in the tooltip, I added that to the codepen in case anyone wants to fiddle with it, they don't have to guess or look up what the ISO2 code is, just hover over and see.

Comment: you're most welcome!  This is a very potent tool in my view.  You'll notice that new questions are raised.