# Amcharts drill-down to countries, adding clickable links

Tags: javascript, maps, amcharts

Adding hyperlinks to maps was already addressed here :
[amcharts drill-down map countries clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501569/amcharts-drill-down-map-countries-clickable)

But I am wondering what I would need to change if I were to instead add clickable hyperlinks to the states or provinces within the countries in the 'drill down to countries' example? 
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/drill-down-to-countries/

For instance, if I were to click on China and view the provinces, how would I assign a URL to its most southern province, Guangxi Zhuang, by using both the methods that you mentioned above?

The ID for that territory is "CN-GX", and can be found in this file :
https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4-geodata/blob/master/dist/es2015/chinaHigh.js

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the linked answer, you can set a `url` propertyField for the PolygonSeries so that it can apply the URL from the data provided to the series. You can combine this with the `done` event handler in the countrySeries (the drilled down map) to populate the series' data with the desired information based on the loaded geodata url. For example:

```
countrySeries.mapPolygons.template.propertyFields.url = "url";
countrySeries.geodataSource.events.on("done", function(ev) {
  worldSeries.hide();
  countrySeries.show();
  if (ev.target.url.indexOf('china') != -1) {
      countrySeries.data = [{
        id: "CN-GX",
        url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guangxi"
      }];
  }
});
```

Obviously you'll want to make this more robust in your application, but you get the idea.

[Demo of your Guangxi scenario](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/cdaf7724cf3641c123a18d2889a65223)